# Can I fill or empty fuel tanks in the VAB?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

I've read about people emptying some of their fuel tanks to save money. How is this done? I've tried everything I can think of short of editing the persistence file.

What I really need to do is fill some tanks, as I've run into this weird bug where some of my tanks have only half of the fuel in them, but 100% of the oxidizer, while in the VAB.

Today I was testing a skycrane by launching it without a booster and landing on Kerbin, and for some reason all of the monopropellant tanks were empty. Weird, because they are full in the VAB and while sitting on the launch pad, and become empty after launching, every time.

I've had the half-empty fuel tanks with other ships before, but this is the first time I've seen the completely empty monopropellant tanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can bring up the parts menu in the VAB/Hangar by right clicking the fuel holding part. This should also work for monoprop. From this menu you can adjust the amount of resource each part is holding at launch.

If your monoprop tanks were empty prematurely, the most likely option is you've activated your response system early and used it all up.

Comment: Thank you Coomie! I knew you could right-click and see how much fuel was in the tank, but I had no idea you could adjust it that way. In fact, that's how I saw that my ship was half empty of fuel in the VAB. After I read your answer I filled the tanks and saved the ship. It hasn't given me a problem since.

Comment: This 5 minute comment crap is a pain. Continued from above:

As for the monoprop, that's just a very weird bug. If you look at the staging, all of the monoprop tanks are shown as a STAGE! So when I went to release the SRBs it didn't work the first press of the spacebar. Instead, the monoprop fired as the next stage! Weird or what?

Comment: @LostOnTheMun That is weird. Are you using some weird mods?

Comment: Yes, I have several mods, and I suspect one of them is probably the cause. I recently installed BurnTogether, EVA Followers, Hullcam and Selectroot. Now that I think of it, I did change the root part on this ship, and I'll bet that's the cause. After you change the root part, it say's something like "rebuilding vessel". Maybe it saw the monoprop as a separate stage.

Comment: @LostOnTheMun If you're using the o-10 monoprop engine, BurnTogether might have used that engine and used up your monoprop.